# React-native error (: Unexpected token, expected ";" (7:5))

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Please, when I run this code, it says: Unexpected token, expected ";" (7:5)

```
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import LoginScreen from './src/screens/LoginScreen';
import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen';
import CreateAccountScreen from './src/screens/CreateAccountScreen';


const AppNavigator =  createStackNavigator (

  {
   Home: HomeScreen,
   Login: LoginScreen,
   CreateAccount: CreateAccountScreen,
  },
  {
   initialRouteName: 'Login',
  },

);

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator (

  {
   Home: HomeScreen,
   Login: LoginScreen,
   CreateAccount: CreateAccountScreen, // remove `,` from here
 },
{
   initialRouteName: 'Login', // remove `,` from here
}, // remove `,` from here

);

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Comment: Thanks. But the problem still persists.